# How to distinguish on an event handler what's the object that triggered it

Tags: events, plone

We have an event handler that is listening to `ObjectModifiedEvent` events for a container content type.

We noticed that whenever an object inside the container is added the container gets this `ObjectModifiedEvent`.

As getting something added to the container is something that this event handler does not care about we were looking for a way to return early if that was the trigger of this event.

We get it to work with something like this:

```
if event.__class__ != ObjectModifiedEvent:
    return
```

Seems that the event argument does not have enough information regarding what's actually the root trigger of this event (as adding an object to a container indeed changes the container), so inspecting the event does not help.

Any other idea apart from the above *hack* to distinguish it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The container emits a `ContainerModifiedEvent` even instance, which is a subclass of `ObjectModifiedEvent`; your test effectively tests if `event` is subclassed or not; a better hack would have been to test the type with `type(event) not is ObjectModifiedEvent`.

You can filter out `ContainerModifiedEvent` explicitly with:

```
from zope.container.interfaces import IContainerModifiedEvent

if IContainerModifiedEvent.providedBy(event):
    return
```

This validates the *interface*, making this work for any implementation of that interface.